# Why does the =~ operator only sometimes have side effects?

Tags: ruby, regex, pattern-matching, irb, oniguruma

I've noticed a side effect in Ruby/Oniguruma that is only present in 1 out of 4 seemingly equivalent statements. Why is the variable `day` defined in `009`, but not in `003`, `005` or `007`?

```
irb(main):001:0> r = /(?<day>\d\d):(?<mon>\d\d)/
=> /(?<day>\d\d):(?<mon>\d\d)/

irb(main):002:0> r =~ "24:12"
=> 0
irb(main):003:0> day
NameError: undefined local variable or method `day' 

irb(main):004:0> "24:12" =~ r
=> 0
irb(main):005:0> day
NameError: undefined local variable or method `day'


irb(main):006:0> "24:12" =~ /(?<day>\d\d):(?<mon>\d\d)/
=> 0
irb(main):007:0> day
NameError: undefined local variable or method `day'


irb(main):008:0> /(?<day>\d\d):(?<mon>\d\d)/ =~ "24:12"
=> 0
irb(main):009:0> day
=> "24"
```

nb#1: It's the same regex and the same string in all four cases.

nb#2: I've verified the behavior in MS Windows and Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Note: although this is not the case here, you should be careful when playing around with local variables in IRb. They may behave slightly differently in IRb than in a script, due to the way the code is being evaluated in IRb. Always write scripts to confirm.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you call `"24:12" =~ r` you actually call `"24:12".=~(r)`. So, [String#=~](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001135) just returns the position the match starts, or nil if there is no match.

But when you call `/(?<day>\d\d):(?<mon>\d\d)/ =~ "24:12"` you actually call [Regexp#=~](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html#M001232)

And as the documentation says

> If =~ is used with a regexp literal
>   with named captures, captured strings
>   (or nil) is assigned to local
>   variables named by the capture names.

what about `003`:

> The assignment is not occur if the
>   regexp is not a literal.

```
   re = /(?<lhs>\w+)\s*=\s*(?<rhs>\w+)/
   re =~ "  x = y  "
   p lhs    # undefined local variable
   p rhs    # undefined local variable
```

and

> The assignment is not occur if the
>   regexp is placed at right hand side.
>   "  x = y  " =~
>   `/(?<lhs>\w+)\s*=\s*(?<rhs>\w+)/`
>   p
>   lhs, rhs # undefined local variable

Comment: Thanks Nash. A very good answer. But can you also explain `003` in the question -- i.e. a compiled regex (not a regex literal) receives the `=~` message and it doesn't assign the local variable.

Comment: "Captured strings is assigned...", "The assignment is not occur..."? Strange grammar...

Comment: @Tim Pietzckerh, you can make it better! ;) http://ruby-doc.org/documentation-guidelines.html

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: the author of that paragraph would probably say the same about your Japanese ;-)

Comment: I just made an error report to ruby about the mistake in the doc (comment).

Answer (score 1):

I believe 003 isn't supported because it's a full blown Regexp object in Rubyland at that point, possibly with overridden methods and such.  That makes the scope of assigned locals a lot more complicated.

Comment: Thanks, James. I had another idea about the intention from the Ruby creators, but you're probably right that it's a technical issue.